# Blogger Soho theme: How to modify function of Jump Link button?

Tags: html, blogger

I am using the Blogger SOHO theme for my Blog:
https://www.firozemistry.com

In the Featured Post, clicking on the Jump Link "Open" opens the page after the first line of text. How do I modify the HTML code to make the Jump Link open the page right at the top?

I have tried poking around in the HTML code of Featured Post widget, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I am a novice, and not well versed in HTML, so I would be most grateful in any help. Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Firoze

Comment: Please share your Featured Post code!

Comment: Hello, the code is too long to copy/paste here. How do I share it?

Comment: Use pastebin.com or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank you. Please see if this link on just fiddle works for you:  https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=eCOefQciu5

Comment: It didn't work try pastebin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to **Theme** > **Edit HTML**
- Click anywhere inside the code area and press CTRL + F
- Search for `fragment &quot;more&quot;` and remove it

**Update**

Put this code before `</body>` tag to remove `#more` from link href

```
<script>
    var link = document.querySelector('.jump-link a');
    link.href = link.href.replace('#more', '');
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @Bassam, thank you for your message. I found only one instance of the code "fragment &quot;more&quot;" and removed it, but it did not work - the Jump Link still opens the page after the first line of text. I there anything else I can try?

Comment: @ Bassam, your script works perfectly! Many thanks for your help, I am much obliged! Kind regards.

Comment: I would like to ask a follow-up question, if I may...  In my Blog, in the Blog Posts gadget, I have changed the default "Read More" jump link text to "Open". However, only for the Featured Post, I would like it to show the default "Read More" text, while for the other snippets I would like it to continue showing "Open". Is there a way to do this please?

Comment: You are welcome, go to your code and replace `<b:include data='post' name='postJumpLink'/>` with `<div class='jump-link flat-button'><a expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title'>Read More</a></div>` Change text "Read More" as you like.

Comment: The code works perfectly. Many thanks once again, you've been most helpful!

Comment: May I ask another question please? On the blog home page, I would like to change the text "Latest Posts" to "Galleries". I tried experimenting with the HTML but was not successful. Could you please help me change the text to "Galleries"? Many thanks!

Comment: @ Bassam, any help for the above question please?

Comment: Yes, search for `<data:messages.latestPosts/>` and replace it with your text.

Comment: @ Bassam, thank you again, this works! Much obliged.

Comment: Hello Bassam, hope you well. I had posted a question here on Stackoverflow  several days ago, but did not get any reply. I would be most grateful if you would have a look at the post and suggest a solution if possible. The link is: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070271/blogger-dynamic-views-mosaic-theme-how-to-get-full-width-images-on-mobile. Many thanks!