# Blogger Dynamic Views (Mosaic theme): how to get full width Images on Mobile?

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, blogger

My Blogger website link is: https://testfnm11.blogspot.com , which is based in the Blogger Dynamic Views Mosaic theme.

When viewing a Page on this site on a mobile phone, I would like the images to display edge-to-edge so as to use the full width of the mobile phone screen.

As an example to show what I want, I have achieved this on my other Blogger site: https://www.firozemistry.com which uses the SOHO theme. I did this by using a CSS code, but that code does not work on the Dynamic Views theme.

ps: For your reference, the CSS code I had used to get edge-to-edge images in my SOHO theme website was:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1162px) {
body.item-view .post-body a[imageanchor="1"] img {
    margin: 0 -30px;
    max-width: calc( 97% + 60px);
    }
```

Could someone please give me a CSS code, or a HTML modification, to achieve edge-to-edge images? I would be most grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Best wishes,
Firoze Mistry

Comment: @Bassam Hello Bassam, would you be able to help me with a solution, please? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1162px) {
  .article .article-content img {
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    margin: 10px -50vw !important;
    max-width: 100vw !important;
    border: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I really do appreciate it. Your CSS code is perfect! Now the images in Mosaic view are almost full screen width, except for a very slight (1mm) border on either side (on Mobile). Sorry to bother you further, but Is there a way to also remove this small (approx 1mm) border? 
(Note that in the Dynamic Views “Classic” view your code does make the images perfectly edge to edge. However in “Mosaic” view there is a slight border on either side). 
Thank in advance!

Comment: You are welcome, The small gap 5px comes from the parent element ".item" inline style. To override the existing position,  you can try this CSS `@media screen and (max-width: 1162px) {.item.open {
    left: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}}` and give me a feedback if any items are affected by these changes.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! Now the borders are gone. And in fact, this CSS solves an issue I did not notice with the previous CSS. I had not noticed that the previous CSS was cropping about 5px of the image on each side. Now by adding this second CSS the cropping is almost gone. I say almost because there is still 1 or 2px border on the left side only, and so that border is cropping 1 or 2 px of the image on the left side. The right side is perfectly fine - no border, and no cropping. Any solution for getting rid of this tiny border on the left side? Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, please try to replace `width: 100% !important;` with `width: 100vw !important;` in the last code.

Comment: Thanks. Replacing 100% with 100vw does make the image edge to edge, but now the webpage wobbles, or moves, side to side if you move it left/right with your finger.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: So, replace `left: 0 !important;` with `left: -1px !important;`.

Comment: Bassam, using -1px moved the border to the right side, while the left side now lined up perfectly. On a hunch, I tried another phone, and discovered this 1px left border is an issue with my iPhone X. Strange! On a iPhone XR, the image lines up perfectly on both edges. So your codes work perfectly! Apologies for the extra trouble I put you thru. And once again many thanks!

Comment: No problem, I also tested on chrome Android and everything works fine, but I think it's a browser issue.